# Is the boundary of (countable) intersction of open sets included in the closure of the union of the boundaries?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\{ U_i \}$ be a family of open sets. From the example of $U_i = (-1/i, 1/i) \subset \mathbb{R}$ for $i \in \mathbb{N}$, I know that it's not true that $\partial( \bigcap\limits_i U_i) \subseteq \bigcup\limits_i \partial(U_i) $. However, I've been trying to prove that

$$ \partial(\bigcap\limits_i  U_i) \subseteq \overline{\bigcup\limits_i \partial(U_i) } $$

In other examples I could think of, this is also true.

My attempt: Let $z \not\in \overline{\bigcup\limits_i \partial(U_i) }$. Then there exists $U$ a neighborhood of $z$ such that $U$ doesn't intersect any $\partial(U_i)$.

If there is some $i$ such that $z \not\in U_i$, then a whole neighborhood of $z$ doesn't intersect $U_i$, so a whole neighborhood of $z$ doesn't intersect $\bigcap\limits_i  U_i$, so $z \not\in \overline{\bigcap\limits_i  U_i}$, so $z \not\in \partial(\bigcap\limits_i  U_i)$.

So we can suppose $U \cap U_i \neq \emptyset$ and $U \cap \partial(U_i) = \emptyset$ for all $i$.
I would like to conclude that $z \in int(\bigcap\limits_i  U_i)$. Is this possible in general, or, if not, is there a counterexample? How about with some assumptions on the space? For example, I'm thinking if the space has a basis of connected open sets, then it would be done if I could conclude that a constant connected component of $U$ is included in each $U_i$, since connected components are open. But is it true that, as intuition has it, the boundary "separates" a set into connected components?

Also, I suspect countability of the family is not necessary, unless Baire's theorem somehow appears, but I'd be surprised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your space is *locally connected*, that is, that every point has a neighborhood basis of connected open sets, the answer is yes and your argument works.  Indeed, if your set $U$ is taken to be connected, then the fact that $U\cap \partial U_i$ is empty implies that either $U\subseteq U_i$, or $U\subseteq U_i^c$ (complement).  Therefore your assumption that $U\cap U_i$ is not empty for every $i$ leads to $U\subseteq U_i$, for every $i$, so you are done!

On the other hand, if your space fails to be locally connected, there are counter-examples: consider the ternary Cantor set $C\subseteq [0,1]$, and let $U_n= [0,3^{-n}]\cap C$.  It is easy to see that each $U_n$ is an open set with empty boundary, so $\cup_n\partial U_n$ is empty but $\cap_n U_n$ is the singleton $\{0\}$, whose boundary coincides with itself.

Comment: Thank you, could you elaborate on why the boundary of each $U_i$ puts connected open sets either on one "side" or another of it, in the local connectedness assumption?

Comment: The whole space decomposes as the disjoint union $\text{int}(U_i) \cup \partial U_i\cup\text{ext}(U_i)$, where ext is the interior of the complement.  If $U$ doesn't meet the boundary then $$U=(U\cap \text{int}(U_i) 
)\cup(U\cap\text{ext}(U_i))
$$ hence a  partition into disjoint open sets.  Since $U$ is connected, one of these is empty.